# Mongodb embedded document as a container for related fields

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoengine

Is it ok to use mongodb embedded document to combine related fields together?

Example: a document has fields `creator_id` and `creator_language`, is it possible to replace them with an embedded document `creator`, containing fields `id` and `language` without performance impact?

I haven't been able to find anything on how an embedded document is stored, except the fact that it has no collection and tied to the parent document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmbeddedDocument are simply nested object inside your document. This is quite standard in mongodb and so its perfectly fine to switch to that. You may observe a performance impact with mongoengine if you start having hundreds or thousands of nested structure but it does not look like this is your plan here.

See below for the storage

```
class DateOfBirth(EmbeddedDocument):
    year = IntField()
    month = IntField()
    day = IntField()

class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()
    dob = EmbeddedDocumentField(DateOfBirth)

Person(name='John', dob=DateOfBirth(day=1, month=12, year=2000)).save()
```

will store an object like this one:

```
# print(Person.objects.as_pymongo().first())
{
  '_id': ObjectId('5d2decf7d8eefe0e58da364d'),
  'name': 'John',
  'dob': {
    'year': 2000,
    'month': 12,
    'day': 1
  }
}
```